# Ipod classic on linux

Tags: linux, ipod

The one piece of software I still occasionally need to use on macos or windows is itunes, as I still have an ipod classic that I sync. Is there something that works natively on linux?

I'm looking for something that can do the following:

- Plays all my music correctly (obviously).
- Displays all the album art for my music (the art I've embedded in the files or stored in the album directory, I don't mind which).
- Sorts my music correctly (respects the sort-related mp3 tags).
- Syncs and plays my audible audiobooks.
- Works with the regular ipod classic firmware (requires nothing like rockbox).
- (I don't care about syncing videos or photos).

I have tried gtkpod, but I couldn't play my music after using it to sync my ipod.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations!